# Google CloudSQL : structuring history data on cloudSQL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm using google cloudSQL for applying advance search on people data to fetch the list of users. In datastore, there are data already stored there with 2 model. First is used to track current data of users and other model is used to track historical timeline. The current data is stored on google cloudSQL are more than millions rows for all users. Now I want to implement advance search on historical data including between dates by adding all history data to cloud.

If anyone can suggest the better structure for this historical model as I've gone through many of the links and articles. But cannot find proper solution as I have to take care of the performance for search (In Current search, the time is taken to fetch result is normal but when history is fetched, It'll scan all the records which causes slowdown of queries because of complex JOINs as needed). The query that is used to fetch the data from cloudSQL are made dynamically based on the users' need. For example, A user want the employees list whose **manager** is **"xyz.123@abc.in"** , by using python code, the query will built accordingly. Now a user want to find users whose manager WAS **"xyz.123@abc.in"** with effectiveFrom 2016-05-02 to 2017-01-01.

As I've find some of the usecases for **structure** as below:

1) Same model as current structure with new column flag for **isCurrentData** (status of data whether it is **history** or **active**)

**Disadv.:**
 - queries slowdown while fetching data as it will scan all records.
   Duplication of data might increase.

These all disadv. will affect the performance of advance search by increasing time.
    Solution to this problem is to partition whole table into diff tables.

2) Partition based on year.
   As time passes, this will generate too many tables.

3) 2 tables might be maintained.
   1st for current data and second one for history. But when user want to search data on both models will create complexity of build query.

So, need suggestions for structuring historical timeline with improved performance and effective data handling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you want to do live queries vs historical queries and the size of your data set, you might want to consider placing the historical data elsewhere.

For example, if you need quick queries for live data and do many of them, but can handle higher-latency queries and only execute them sometimes, you might consider periodically exporting data to Google BigQuery. BigQuery can be useful for searching a large corpus of data but has much higher latency and doesn't have a wire protocol that is MySQL-compatible (although it's query language will look familiar to those who know any flavor of SQL). In addition, while for Cloud SQL you pay for data storage and the amount of time your database is running, in BigQuery you mostly pay for data storage and the amount of data scanned during your query executions. Therefore, if you plan on executing many of these historical queries it may get a little expensive.

Also, if you don't have a very large data set, BigQuery may be a bit of an overkill. How large is your "live" data set and how large do you expect your "historical" data set to grow over time? Is it possible to just increase the size of the Cloud SQL instance as the historical data grows until the point at which it makes sense to start exporting to Big Query?

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin Malachowski : Thanks for guiding me with your info and questions as It gave me new way of thinking.

Historical data records will be more than 0.3-0.5 million(maximum). Now I'll use **BigQuery** for historical advance search.

For live data-**cloudSQL** will be used as we must focus on perfomance for fetched data.

Some of performance issue will be there for historical search, when a user wants both results from live as well as historical data. (BigQuery is taking time near about 5-6 sec[or more] for worst case) But it will be optimized as per data and structure of the model.